# Pre-populating Selected Values in Django Admin FilteredSelectmultiple Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-admin, default-value

I want to be able to set some default selected users on the right side of a Django Admin FilteredSelectMultiple widget.

[image]

This is my model:

```
class UserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Users",
                                      is_stacked=False))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ()
```

Is there a way to do this with JavaScript so that I don't have to hand-select these defaults each time I create a new item?

Comment: How do you determine *what* items should be moved to the right initially?

Comment: There is a common set that are used each time out of a large list of options.

Comment: what if you use `users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(initial=User.objects.filter(username__in=['johnsmith', 'janedoe']), queryset=User.objects.all(), widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Users", is_stacked=False))`

Comment: thus specifying as initial a queryset with hardcoded usernames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the initial data by setting the [**`initial=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial) with:

```
class UserAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        initial=User.objects.filter(username__in=['johnsmith', 'janedoe']),
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple('Users', is_stacked=False)
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Here we thus set as initial selected users `johnsmith` and `janedoe`. You can of course pick other users.